# Applying bubble sort using pointer to pointer concept?

Tags: c

I am sorting an array alphabetically using bubble sort while applying the pointer to pointer concept. My program crashes when I use strcpy function to swap address of array *b[4] using pointer to pointer **p[4], apart from that the program works fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
 {
   char a[][10]={"milk","eggs","bread","cheese"};
   char *b[4],**p[4],*temp;
   int length[4];
   int i,j;

   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      length[i]=strlen(a[i]);
      b[i]=(char *)calloc(length[i],sizeof(char));
      strcpy(b[i],a[i]);
      p[i]=&b[i];
    }

  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
     for(i=0; i<3-j; i++)
      {
        if(strcmp(*p[i],*p[i+1])>0)
          { /*         
            strcpy(temp,*p[i]);    This is the part of the code where the  
            strcpy(*p[i],*p[i+1]); program crashes, can someone please point            
            strcpy(*p[i+1],temp);  out the logical flaw
             */
          }
       }
    }  

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
    puts(*p[i]);
   }  


}
```

Comment: You are not leaving room for the null-terminator when you allocate.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program crashes is that you are trying to copy the content of a C string into an uninitialized pointer `temp`, causing undefined behavior.

Even if you fix this by supplying a buffer of appropriate length for the `temp`, you would get undefined behavior on copying longer strings into space allocated for shorter strings (e.g. when copying `"cheese"` into the space that has been allocated for `"eggs"`). Moreover, your current implementation currently has undefined behavior, too, because it fails to allocate enough space to accommodate null terminator of your strings.

A proper way of fixing this is to swap pointers, rather than using them to copy the content.

Comment: Thank You for pointing out my conceptual mistakes. By uninitialized do you mean that pointer temp does not point to a location in memory? If one is to store address in an uninitialized pointer, is that also considered undefined behavior?

Comment: @AMD Correct, uninitialized means that `temp` does not point to a location in memory. It's OK to store an address in the pointer itself, this would initialize the pointer. After that storing data into the location pointed to by the pointer becomes valid, up to the limits of the block of memory to which the pointer is pointing.

Comment: Could you please explain the statement "up to the limits of the block of memory" briefly if you don't mind.

Comment: @AMD You set a pointer to a location in some memory region, e.g. to a result of `malloc` call. If you `malloc`, say, 100 bytes, it is legal to write an object of size of up to 100 bytes into that location, e.g. a string of 99 characters plus its null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

In `strcpy(temp,*p[i])`, `temp` is expected to point to memory into which the string should be copied. You never initialized `temp`, causing undefined behaviour.

But as you mentioned, all you need is to copy the pointer.

```
temp = p[i];
p[i] = p[i+1];
p[i+1] = temp;
```

---

Cleaned up solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   const char *a[] = { "milk", "eggs", "bread", "cheese" };
   size_t n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

   const char** p;
   { /* Make p a shallow copy of a so that we don't change a */
      p = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));

      {
         size_t i;
         const char** src = a;
         const char** dst = p;
         for (i=n; i--; )
            *(dst++) = *(src++);
      }
   }

   { /* Sort p using bubble sort */
      size_t i;
      int swapped = 1;
      while (swapped) {
         swapped = 0;
         for (i=0; i<n-1; ++i) {
            if (strcmp(p[i], p[i+1]) > 0) {
               const char* temp = p[i];
               p[i] = p[i+1];
               p[i+1] = temp;
               swapped = 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   {
      size_t i;
      for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
         puts(p[i]);
   }

   free(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: My compiler seems to be giving me an error: initialization from  incompatible pointer type on line char** src = a; I don't seem to understand why?

Comment: Fixed. . . . . .

Comment: I just ran the above posted code, it compiles successfully, but the program crashes?

Comment: No, it runs fine. You probably ran the old one (that did `i+i` instead of `i+1`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
 for(i=0; i<3-j; i++)
```

j will iterate till it is less than  4, that means i will iterate till it is less than -1?

1. i started from 0 and it is incremented by one.
2. array index can never be equal to -1(because it starts from 0).

also, change the above line to this

```
 for(i=0; i<(j); i++)
```

the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your desire to allocate and copy is for purpose of simple exercise, but in approaching the problem that way you wildly over-complicate what should be a simple pointer-swap to sort `a`. For example, why declare `a` as a *2D array of char* instead of an *array of pointers to char* (e.g. `char *a[] = {....}`)?

By declaring `a` as an array of pointers, you simply need to swap pointers in your sort -- no allocation or copying required, e.g.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void) {

    char *a[] = {"milk","eggs","bread","cheese"};
    size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a, i, j;

    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for(i = 0; i < n - 1 - j; i++)
            if(strcmp(a[i], a[i+1]) > 0) {        
                char *tmp = a[i];  
                a[i] = a[i+1];            
                a[i+1] = tmp;
            }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("a[%zu] : %s\n", i, a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile VS (cl.exe)**

```
>cl /nologo /Wall /wd4710 /Ox /Foobj/bsarrayptr /Febin/bsarrayptr /Tc bsarrayptrs.c
```

**Compile gcc**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/bsarrayptr bsarrayptrs.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\bsarrayptr.exe
a[0] : bread
a[1] : cheese
a[2] : eggs
a[3] : milk
```

If your intent was just to perform an exercise using additional levels of indirection, copying and allocation, that's fine, but if you intent was to handle a alphabetical sort of `a`, then simply swapping pointers is a much more efficient approach.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.